# Word Vba Add Row to Repeating Section Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Word 2016, is there a way through VBA to add a new entry to a repeating section content control? I have my repeating section content control set up, and it is the only content control in the document (there is actually no other content in the document). I want to add a new repeated row, to this content control.

I have tried recording a macro to see what it spits out but nothing was recorded when I added a new row manually. Maybe at this point I should realize that I am SOL, but I was wondering if there was some way that I could complete this that was not being recognized by my recorded macro.

The application: I want to print out labels onto a sheet of label stock, there are 10 labels on the label stock but not every print uses all 10 labels, so I want to be able to decide how many labels are printed and what is the starting location of the print on the label stock. The information that is going onto the labels is already being input into a form on Excel which can then open up the word document and set the content controls based on the excel input (this part is already figured out)

Comment: Perhaps you can help me understand what you mean by "Content control". The way I understand the task, there would be a table with 10 cells per page. Some of the cells would be blank, either at the top where there are no more labels on the sheet, or at the bottom where you want nothing printed on existing labels.

Comment: @Variatus I have set up content controls [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj889465.aspx) within each cell of the table in the form of a repeating section content control. In this manner, in each cell there is a content control title "Part Number" and each has a unique index. I would hope to cycle through the indices of the content controls and add information programatically from the information the user has already entered into my excel userform. Your explanation of my desired task is correct.

Comment: I believe what you want to do is to insert a copy of your existing content control. You can do that with Copy and Paste, using either the Selection or the Range object. The following link deals with a very similar problem and seems to offer a solution. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66516e31-cccd-4f02-bf2a-00af4c280d5d/repeating-section-content-control-placeholder-text?forum=worddev