# Is it possible to add Repeating Section Content Control section with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have created Word template with **Repeating Section Rontent Control (RSCC)** containing other **Content Controls**. Also I have excel workbook with information which should go to mentioned Word template. The thing I am trying to do is to create macro which would fill Word template with information from selected rows in Excel workbook (each row to new RSCC section).

I have quite good idea how to do that, except one thing- I cannot figure out how to write macro which would add another section to **Repeating Section Content Control**.

I am adding illustrations of what I am trying to do:

[image: example]

Problem is, that I cannot find code to do the same thing with VBA. I have tried recording process, but recorded macro is empty (?!).

Looking for answer I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571084/word-vba-add-row-to-repeating-section-content-control) in StackOverflow, it ask similar question to mine, but it was more or less unanswered to my understanding. Comment in this thread forwarded to old thread in [Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66516e31-cccd-4f02-bf2a-00af4c280d5d/repeating-section-content-control-quotplaceholder-textquot?forum=worddev), but I did not find solution to this problem (or at least I did not understand clearly how should I approach it).

Since one thread is almost 5 years old, another 2 years old. My question is it even possible to add another section to RSCC with VBA? Maybe somebody found a way to do this in the past year or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Word object model has a collection and object for a repeating section content control: `RepeatingSectionItems` and `RepeatingSectionItem`. The latter has two insert methods, to insert before or after the `RepeatingSectionItem`.

Here's a sample that shows how to reference a repeating section content control in a document, get the first or last item and insert a new one after it.

```
Sub AddRepeatingSection()
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
    Dim repCC As Word.RepeatingSectionItem

    Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("RepCC").Item(1)
    Set repCC = cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(1)
    'Or to get the last one:
    'Set repCC = cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count)
    repCC.InsertItemAfter        
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like charm. I have managed to find "sort of" solution to this, by copying and pasting CC to designated bookmark, but I wasn't happy with my solution. My code: `ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("New_reg").Item(1).Range.Copy
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="paste_here"
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)`