# Indexing of repeating content control items

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883276/is-it-possible-to-add-repeating-section-content-control-section-with-vba/55102091#55102091) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53884956/9889161) solution:

I have a similar problem, but I need to insert items in order, but I could not index the inserted repeating content controls correctly. I do not know how many items I should insert in advance, so inserting could be fully dynamic. 
Could anybody help me?

Here is a simple code:

```
Dim wordApp As Variant
Dim wDoc As Variant

Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/example.docm")
wordApp.Visible = True


Dim i As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1

Dim cc As Variant
Dim repCC As Variant
Set cc = wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("container").Item(1)


For i = 1 To 4
        If counter <> 1 Then
            Set repCC = cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count)
            repCC.InsertItemAfter
        End If

        wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("number").Item(counter).Range.Text = counter
        counter = counter + 1

Next i
```

A picture of my word doc:

[image]

The tag name of the repeating content control is "container". The tag name of the rich text content control is "number".

A picture of the wrong result:

[image]

And what I would like to get :)

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: So you're saying the value of number should change dynamically each time a new repeating content control is inserted? Have you tried inserting SEQ fields for the numbering sequence? These don't update automatically, it requires manually updating field codes (select, then press F9) or running a macro to do so. But the numbering itself will be SEQuential.

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister for your comment and help! 
The task is not about counting (it is only a simplified example). My problem is when inserting a new repeating content control, I could not fill out their inner content controls in the correct order. Each tags of the inner content controls are the same, so I think they are identified by their indexes with .Item(1, 2, …) method. I thought when inserting a new repeating content control, it goes under the previous one and the indexes of its inner content controls are increasing by one. But something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could resolve my problem:

**TASK:** This is a simply example of inserting Repeating Section Content Controls (RSCC) dynamically from vba and fill out their inner Content Controls in order.

**PROBLEM:** When inserting a new RSCC like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883276/is-it-possible-to-add-repeating-section-content-control-section-with-vba/53884956#53884956), their Content Controls will get the same tags (titles), and indexes are assigned randomly.

**SOLUTION:** Content controls must be filled out on the fly, when a new RSCC has been just inserted.

```
Dim cc As Variant
Dim repCC As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set cc = wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("container").Item(1)

For i = 1 To 4 'it could be any number
        If i = 1 Then 'because already has a RSCC in the doc file, so I need only 3 more.
            Set repCC = cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(1)
        Else
            repCC.InsertItemAfter
            Set repCC = cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(i) '(or .Item(cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count))
        End If

        For Each cc_current In repCC.Range.ContentControls
            Select Case cc_current.Tag
                Case Is = "number"
                    cc_current.Range.Text = i
                'Case Is = .....
            End Select
        Next cc_current
Next i
```