# Word 2016- How to add/delete Repeating Section Content Control in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to write vba code to add and delete repeating item section for specifically named RSCC.

The following code works for adding but cannot figure out how to delete

[Is it possible to add Repeating Section Content Control section with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883276/is-it-possible-to-add-repeating-section-content-control-section-with-vba)

Comment: Have you tried using the ObjectBrowser, or pressing F1 to bring up the documentation? All the information you need is there.

Comment: What is the ObjectBrowser?  F1 takes me to the Word Help.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time learning how to use the Visual Basic Editor. You can find help [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-user-interface-help), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-browser). Pressing F1, or choosing Help from the context menu, whilst in the VBE with your cursor in a keyword, or selected in the Object Browser, will take you to the online VBA documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete repeating item section for specifically named RSCC just edit the code you found in the other question.

```
Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("RepCC").Item(1)
'to delete the first RepeatingSectionItem
cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(1).Delete
'to delete all but the first RepeatingSectionItem
Dim index As Long
For index = cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -1
  cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(index).Delete
Next index
'to delete the entire ContentControl
cc.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy for these codes and I got them to work but how do I to delete the last repeating section one by one while never deleting the first one?  You showed me how to delete the first repeating section and all but the first.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - I don’t know what you are defining as “the last” but delete all but first starts from the last one and works backwards.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- If I have 5 sections (1,2,3,4,5) and I run a macro with the 'delete all but the first RepeatingSectionItem' code, it goes to 1 section with one click.  What I am trying to do is run a macro and sections 1,2,3,4,5 becomes 1,2,3,4 with one click.  Click the macro again and it becomes 1,2,3.  Click the macro again and it becomes 1,2.  Click the macro again and it becomes 1.  But on top of that, I want to make sure that if I click that macro again, it will not delete that first section.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - well you now have all of the information you need to be able to do that. You already know how to identify the last one and how to count the number of items. I am not going to write all your code for you.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - Your question has already been answered in full. You already know how to count the number of items, `cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count`, how to identify the last repeating item, `cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count)`, and how to add and delete items. It is now time for you to use that knowledge and write some code. The logic for what you are trying to do is very simple.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- I figured out the problem. I guess I didn't know it mattered hence why you are so confused lol. This code works for preset sections whereas I need the code to work whether I have 3,5,7 or any number sections. ```To 2 Step -2``` works for 3 sections but if I added 2 more quickly, I would have to manually change it ``To 2 Step -4`` (for 5 sections). If I added 2 more sections again, I would have to manually change it again ```To 2 Step -6``` (for 7 sections).  How can I account for a change or indefinite number of sections so I dont have to manually edit with each change?

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - as I stated previously this question has already been answered in full. If you need any further help with code that you have written as a result of the knowledge you have gained here you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- oh....you mean like start a whole new thread or add another answer to this one?

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - yes, start a whole new thread.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- Wow.  I am so sorry.  This is my first time on stackoverflow.  Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - that’s ok. Lots of first timers don’t realise that SO isn’t a “forum” in the traditional sense, essentially it is more like third line support for developers. That is why each question (or thread) needs to be focussed and specific.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

This macro will insert a repeating section CC:

```
Sub AddRepeatingSectionCC()
  Dim oCC As ContentControl
  Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRepeatingSection, Selection.Range)
  With oCC
    .AllowInsertDeleteSection = True
    .RepeatingSectionItemTitle = "Repeating Section Item"
  End With
  Set oCC = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here's a second macro to set the other CC options:

```
Sub SetOptions()
  If Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
    With Selection.ParentContentControl
      'Sets the appearance to the original bounding box look. For the newer tags look, use wdContentControlTags
      'If you don't need to change a setting, comment it out before running the macro
      .Appearance = wdContentControlBoundingBox

      'Sets the color of the control to a preset color
      .Color = wdColorWhite

      'Sets whether the Content Control can be deleted or not. If the control has had .Temporary = True applied, you must reverse that property to True before applying this.
      .LockContentControl = True

      'Sets whether the contents of the Content Control can be deleted or not.
      .LockContents = False

      'Sets the placeholder text or prompt for the control
      .SetPlaceholderText , , "Default Text"

      'Sets the Content Control tag property
      .Tag = "Tag"

      'If this is set to true, the Content Control will be removed when the contents are edited.
      .Temporary = False

      'Sets the title of the Content Control. This appears on a tab above the control when it is activated.
      .Title = "Title"
    End With
  Else
    MsgBox "Please select a Content Control to change its options."
  End If
End Sub
```

To delete it:

```
Sub DeleteCC()
  If Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
    Selection.ParentContentControl.Delete
  Else
    MsgBox "Please select a Content Control to delete it."
  End If
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thank you John.  I am new to this site.  How do I respond to you when I need longer than 580 characters as I have more questions?  When I click edit, it says "suggested edit queue is full"

Comment: John, can this vba be used to delete a selected control, or must that be done through either the interface or other code?

Comment: Both `ContentControl` and `RepeatingSectionItem` have a `Delete` method, as either the Object Browser or online documentation will show.

Comment: Mohamad, I've added a sub to delete a selected control.

Comment: Thanks John, can you look at my most recent post from yesterday and let me know?  I should have started off with that first but still, your initial response was still informative